# Redis Celery broker not reachable when deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I want to deploy celery in production on Heroku. Until now I was working under development, now I want to deploy the celery in production. Its a Django app. It works fine locally.

My current settings are :

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

But when I deploy it, and try to test a celery task, the server (Heroku) logs says

```
Connection error: Error 111 connecting localhost:6379. Connection refused.. Trying again in 20.0 seconds...
2014-03-18T15:24:03.823030+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:24:03 celery.1 | [2014-03-18 15:24:03,822: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: Error 111 connecting localhost:6379. Connection refused..
```

Obviously, `BROKER_URL` being linked to `localhost:6379` would not be connected.

**Which URL should I point to when deploying in production??**

**UPDATED**

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'LlumprsWebsite.settings')

app = Celery('LlumprsWebsite')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

**settings.py**

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1` ? Since your deployment seems to be on heroku it is possible that localhost is not used as an alias.

Comment: I have barely used heroku but maybe you have a specific URL for the instance that is deployed in production ? Maybe in the Redis settings page of your project ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the setting of celery that I've included in project. Kindly have look..

Comment: Looks like Redis on Heroku have a specific URL calls [`REDIS_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)

Comment: Its asking me to verify my account. Upon verifying the acc., it asks me to add Credit Card details. Thought its basic version is free, but I dont have a credit card.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49961/discussion-between-bvidal-and-user1162512)

Answer (score 0):

BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0' won't work on the heroku server. You need to install any of the two add-on in heroku for redis

- https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo
- https://addons.heroku.com/rediscloud

both add-ons provide free tier plan.

after that you can specify your brocker url

BROKER_URL = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

so it will work on both local and heroku server.

You can find detailed documentation in

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#install-redis-in-python
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-python

One more thing. I personally prefer **redistogo** for the heroku. Because redistogo has got more features than rediscloud.

Note: There are more redis add-ons available in heroku. but they don't provide free tier plan. :)

Comment: Redis Cloud advocate here - thanks for the mention but AFAIK we offer more, including changing plans w/o downtime and limitless scaling. What features are you referring to?